# Java main within Tomcat project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, program-entry-point

I have a running and working Tomcat Project and I want to add a normal Java project into it for better and faster testing. No pages to get fast database outputs and such.

In the `WEB-INF/src` folder I have added a package with contains my main class and includes some of the other controllers from the project.

EDIT: Moved sources to the /src (as suggested) folder but still the same error.

Right now it is a simple `println` in a main class. The problem is that eclipse tells me it cannot find the main clas or load it. (`right click on the main class file -> runs as -> Java Application`)

```
package mytomcatproj.maintest
import mytomcatproj.othercontroller

public class MyMainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String overval="te";
        String overres= othercontroller.getWord(overval);
        System.out.println("Test" + overres);
    }
 }
```

How can I get the project to run?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Please share the console output of eclipse.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You need to put your source code under `src/main/java`. You should consider revisiting the project structure with [recommendations](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)

Comment: “Error: Could not find or load main class mytomcatproj.maintest.MyMainClass” is the error

Comment: @soufrk same problem when I move the source